# RF Reflectivity and Transmission

Tags: radio-frequency

There appear to be abundant graphs and data available for various materials in the upper RF ranges. Where would one go to find reflectivity and transmission coefficients for a variety of materials in the lower RF, $300~\text{kHz}$ - $300 ~\text{MHz}$ (MF, HF, and VHF) range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably be very difficult to find experimental data on electromagnetic wave reflectivity and transmission of materials in this frequency range because of the large size of the material required to do the measurements. For such measurements you need slabs of materials (experimental setups) that are large compared to the wavelengths considered, which for the frequencies given would be between 1km and 1m. In this frequency range, it is much easier to measure the (complex) dielectric constant of the material (e.g., with high frequency bridges and capacitors) and to calculate the reflection and transmission using basic electromagnetic wave theory.